# Как вывести на консоль список без скобок

Tags: python, list, список

Программа выводит на консоль список в виде

[['Муму'], ['Сияние'], ['Колобок']]

Как убрать скобки и запятые?

Comment: воспользоваться поиском и найти один из 111555 ответов на похожий вопрос

Comment: Добавлял, но получал вот такой вывод:
['Муму'] ['Сияние'] ['Колобок']  - т.е. убираются только две внешние скобки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно с помощью цикла:

```
lst = [['Муму'], ['Сияние'], ['Колобок']]
for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end=' ')
```

Comment: Спасибо! ) с помощью цикла for получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
list = [['cat'], ['dog']]
for i in list:
    print(*i)
```